# Jquery and Bootstrap not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button that is used to navigate in between slides. The button works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox. In the first slide it works fine but as soon as I move to the second slide and click the button to go to the third slide the button dissapears from the page. I've already checked and jquery-ui is loading before boostrap js.

Generated HTML:

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.fullPage.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

In Firebug I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
Source File: chrome://web-developer/content/overlay/javascript/overlay.js
Line: 7333
```

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.fullpage({
            fixedElements: '.btn-success',
            'verticalCentered': false
        });

        $('.btn-success').click(function(){
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class='btn btn-lg btn-success'>Down</div>
<div class="section " id="section0"><h1>1 Slide</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section2"><h1>2 slide</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section3"><h1>3 slide</h1></div>
```

Is this a Firefox bug or is my code wrong?

Comment: what about a jsfiddle to see whats happen atm?

Comment: That looks like an error coming from a Firefox add-on. You should try your page on a clean Firefox profile and see if it happens there.

Comment: @Pointy how can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you do it on Windows; on Linux, you start the browser with a command line option: `firefox -ProfileManager`

Comment: Alternatively, you can just look through your addons and disable any that you think might be suspicious.

Comment: Running firebug I found a bug on the following line: eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue with the web developer toolbar add-on in Firefox.

The author of the add-on (chrispederick.com) is aware of the problem according to a forum post on his site (edit: forum is no more), but so far no fix has been released.

Comment: Good to know that it's a problem with that addon, I was slowly going nuts. Pity though that it still hasn't been fixed and strange that I haven't seen it on other sites, just the one I finished developing recently.

Comment: The error is still there - line 7333, col 5. Page apparently continues to execute.

Comment: FWIW, the referenced link in this answer no longer exists. The web developer toolbar issue is still present.